# Flutter heavy platform code causes UI lag

Tags: android, flutter, dart-isolates

I'm using `MethodChannel.invoke` to call some platform code to return app icons as `Uint8List`s. This happens for a list of all the apps on a device (can be quite a lot), displayed as `FutureBuilder`s in a `ListView.builder`.

This caused a lot of stutter when scrolling quickly in the `ListView`, so I changed it so that all the app icons are preloaded before displaying the ListView. This fixes the scrolling, but the UI is very janky while the icons are loading.

I believe the problem may be the same as [this issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/18999), and I shouldn't be loading the icons on the UI thread the way it is now. However, looking at the [docs for `compute`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/compute.html), I don't think I will be able to use it to call platform code.

Is there another way I can avoid the UI lag?

Comment: why cannot you use `compute` function?

Comment: It's not supported yet: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937

Comment: so use `HandlerThread` on android and ??? on iOS (sorry i have no idea about iOS)

Answer (score 2):

pskink's suggestion of using a `HandlerThread` did the trick! I now can scroll smoothly even without preloading.